# How to use value in onClick event in customBodyRender in MuiDataTable?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

When using `customBodyRender` the values from `tableMeta` shows correctly in a `console.log()`and if I choose to return for instance `<span>{tableMeta.rowData[0]}</span>` it will give the right id. However if I try to use the value in a onClick event the `tableMeta` will always show the data from the last row. (See [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-mclaren-ivvlq?file=/src/App.js))

```
options: {
        viewColumns: false,
        filter: false,
        customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
          console.log(tableMeta); // works
          return (
            <div>
              <span>{tableMeta.rowData[0]}</span> // works
              <button onClick={() => console.log(tableMeta.rowData[0])}>btn</button> // does not work
            </div>
          )...
```

I came over this question in Spanish Stack Overflow and I wasn't able to find any solution to it. I'm very curious if there's any way to work around this?

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-mclaren-ivvlq?file=/src/App.js